# MaxScale - Mask every column in all tables of a DataBase and specify which not

Tags: mariadb, proxy-server, data-masking, maxscale

What I am looking for is to mask all the columns (and new columns that could be added in the future to the tables in my DB).

So for that I want to know if there is a way to mask everything and specify which column names to be excluded of masking.

I looked into the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-6-masking/#configuration) and didn't find something related so I dont know if this functionality exists.

What I have tried is the following:

```bash
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "replace": {
                "database":"myDB",
        "match":"\\s+(.*)"
            },
            "with": {
                "fill": "X"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I get the error:

```bash
Error: Server at http://myhost:4919 responded with 400 Bad Request to `POST filters`
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "detail": "A masking rule 'replace' does not have the mandatory 'column' key or it's not a valid Json string."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How about creating a `VIEW` with the columns you _do_ want?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I get the point of creating a `VIEW`. It will get all the columns from the tables, I could create the masking rule JSON for Maxscale based on that list. But in the future, more tables will automatically be added, and I want to avoid doing the task of adding one by one say the next year.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: The `VIEW` can be `SELECT col1, col4, ...` -- That is leave out columns you want to hide.  It will look and act much like a table with fewer columns.

Comment: As for this being a recurring task, I suggest the whole design philosophy is "wrong" ro an RDBMS.